# Javascript - clone array inside itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

I have an array ["0", "1", "2"] and I need to create function that makes it 
["0", "1","2", "0", "1", "2"]. I wrote that clone function:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr.clone = function() {
    var b = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        b.push(arr[i]);
    }
    var c = b.concat(b);
    return c;
}
arr.clone();
```

Am I doing it right? Maybe there's a better or shorter way to clone the elements?

Answer (score 11):

You only have to use [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) by itself, since it builds a new array:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr = arr.concat(arr);  // [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2]
const combinedOne = [ ...arr, ...arr]
```

With es6, we can use the spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
Array.prototype.self2 = function () {
    return ( Array.prototype.push.apply( this, this ), this );
};
console.log( [1,2,"a"].self2() );
//
//  [1, 2, "a", 1, 2, "a"]
//
```

Comment: I'm years late, but thanks for answering. However, it should be noted that it's generally bad practice to mess with a native JS class's prototype. Also note the OP's comment on Joon's answer, which explains how a similar method can lead to another property(s) being included in the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also write the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method, in this way:

```js
let arrayA = [0, 1, 2];
arr = [].concat(arr, arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Frédéric Hamidi's answer is probably the best answer if all of your target browsers support `Array.concat` method, and you don't mind creating a new array.

Here's how you can keep the old array reference without creating a new array, and is fully cross-browser.

```
arr.push.apply(arr, arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The thing's that in my task I need to add function clone to my array's prototype. And when I try to push array into itself this function clone's added too. So I get something like that
`[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, foo: function]`