# duplicate same elements in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to duplicate array with same elements that contains the first array
For example, I have this array

```
let array1 = [{title: "test1"}, {title: "Test2"}, {title: "test3"}];
```

I need to transform it into

```
array1 = [{title: "test1"}, {title: "Test2"}, {title: "test3"}, {title: "test1"}, {title: "Test2"}, {title: "test3"}];
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653302/javascript-clone-array-inside-itself

Comment: `array1.concat(array1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to concat, like:

```
let array1 = [{title: "test1"}, {title: "Test2"}, {title: "test3"}];

array1 = array1.concat(array1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot <3

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but here's a solution.

```
let array1 = [{title: "test1"}, {title: "Test2"}, {title: "test3"}];  
array1 = [ ...array1, ...array1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot <3

Answer (score -2):

You can also achieve it with a little `for` loop :)

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3] ;
let new_array = [] ;
for(let i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    new_array = new_array.concat(arr) ;
}

console.log(new_array) ;
```

Comment: Maybe because you need to replace 3 by the expected repetition ? ... Maybe you should take a better look A_A